# Is it overkill to define template displayFor views for almost every object in program?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Is it reasonable to define a DisplayFor/EditorFor template for every object in my model?

The benefit is code reuse. *Is there any downside?*

A simple data model, where each of these classes would have its own display/editor template: Zoo, Enclosure, Animal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you want to create DisplayFor/EditorFor templates for all objects in your model? Are all of them really that reusable?

I haven't seen such a solution before but I think it's mainly a matter of taste. Usually you'll find the layout logic in the Views but with your solution there would instead be DisplayFor() and EditorFor() calls in there and the real layout logic would be in the templates.

If an object is rendered in exactly the same way in several different views then your solution would definitely be a good idea. If not, then it is, as said before, mainly a matter of taste if you ask me.

I don't see any problems from a performance point of view neither. If performance should be a concern you can always select to pre-compile your views to gain a bit more.